# how can i use an inputed variable from user in a loop and outside the loop

Tags: java, loops, variables

```
char answer = input.next().charAt(0);
     for (int i =1 ;i!=0 ; ) {
         
        
         int j = 0 ; 
    if ( answer=='*' ||  answer=='/' || answer=='+' || answer=='-') {
        i= 0 ; 
    }
    else 
    {
        i=1; 
        
        while ( j<i) {
            System.out.println( " please reenter the operation ") ; 
            //answer=input.next().charAt(0) ; 
            j++ ; 
        }
        
     }
  
}
```

in this code i declared the variable answer outside the loop to run the code
but in my main code i tried to put the variable inside the loop
as here for example

```
     for (int i =1 ;i!=0 ; ) {
        char answer = input.next().charAt(0)  ; 
}
```

.......

so the variable outside the loop  can't be used

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd follow a pattern more like this:

```
char answer;
boolean invalid;    
do {
  System.out.print("Operation: ");
  answer = input.nextLine().charAt(0);
  invalid = (answer != '*' && answer != '/' && answer != '+' && answer != '-');
  if (invalid) {
    System.out.println("Invalid operation. Please re-enter!");
  }
} while (invalid);

// ... do something with "answer" here ...
```